# How would I model these grooves / holes in this handle

Tags: modeling, topology

I am trying to model a gun grip and I am almost finished with it except theres 1 part and I am not sure on how I would be able to do it

Here is my handle

[image]

And this is what I am trying to add

[image]

This is what the topology looks like before the subdivision

[image]

Can anybody assist me with this?

Comment: This could be accomplished as part of the texture

Comment: +1 to @AllenSimpson, although it's not unheard of to model this into the HP mesh to get that texture onto the lp. Can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file?

Comment: I'm with @Allen on this. If you want real geometry instead, you'll have to get more polygons to work with and apply the subdivision modifier first :)